# div class container display out side bottom border of page so how to solve this issue?

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work on asp.net mvc application . I face issue on print report div container .

this issue happen on bottom section that have signature date and reference No that display out side bottom border

div class container is my issue it display outside bottom border .

I display signature and date on the bottom of page but this section display on second page and outside bottom border so how to solve that

so How to solve this issue

```
 <div style="height: 190px;margin-top:-20px;">
            <table width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 76mm; height:30px;">
                            <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-size:11px">Name</label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-size:11px">Position</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:38mm;">
                            <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-size:11px">Status / Signature</label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-size:11px">Date</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>


            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CreatedByName))
            {

                <tr style="height: 5px;">
                    <td style="width: 76mm;">
                        <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">@Model.CreatedByName</label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 38mm;">
                        <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Requester</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:38mm;">

                        <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Requested</label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 38mm;">
                        <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">@Model.CreatedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }




                @if (Model.LineManagerUserName != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.LineManagerUserName.ToString()) && Model.LineManagerUser > 0)
                {
                    <tr style="height: 5px;">
                        <td style="width: 76mm;">
                            <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">@Model.LineManagerUserName</label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Line Manager</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.LineManagerApproved == true)
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Approved</label>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Rejected</label>
                            }

                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.LineManagerApprovalDate != null)
                            {
                                <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">
                                    @Model.LineManagerApprovalDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                </span>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

                @if (Model.DepartementHeadUserName != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.DepartementHeadUserName.ToString()) && Model.DepartementHeadUser > 0)
                {
                    <tr style="height: 5px;">
                        <td style="width: 76mm;">
                            <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">@Model.DepartementHeadUserName</label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Department Head</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.DepartementHeadApproved == true)
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Approved</label>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Rejected</label>
                            }

                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.DepartementHeadApprovalDate != null)
                            {
                                <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">
                                    @Model.DepartementHeadApprovalDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                </span>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                @if (Model.PlanningUser != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.PlanningUser.ToString()) && Model.PlanningUser > 0)
                {
                    <tr style="height: 5px;">
                        <td style="width: 76mm;">
                            <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">@Model.PlanningUserName</label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Planning</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.PlanningApproved == true)
                            {
                                @*<label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Approved</label>*@
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Reviewed</label>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Rejected</label>
                            }

                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.PlanningApprovalDate != null)
                            {
                                <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">
                                    @Model.PlanningApprovalDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                </span>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

                @if (Model.RecruitmentUserName != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.RecruitmentUserName.ToString()) && Model.RecruitmentUser > 0)
                {
                    <tr style="height: 5px;">
                        <td style="width: 76mm;">
                            <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">@Model.RecruitmentUserName</label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Recruitment</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.RecruitmentApproved == true)
                            {
                                @*<label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Approved</label>*@
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Reviewed</label>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Rejected</label>
                            }

                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.RecruitmentApprovalDate != null)
                            {
                                <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">
                                    @Model.RecruitmentApprovalDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                </span>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }






                @if (Model.HREDUser != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.HREDUser.ToString()) && Model.HREDUser > 0)
                {
                    <tr style="height: 5px;">
                        <td style="width: 76mm;">
                            <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">@Model.HREDUserName</label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">HRE Director</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.HREDApproved == true)
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Approved</label>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Rejected</label>
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            @if (@Model.HREDApprovalDate != null)
                            {
                                <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">
                                    @Model.HREDApprovalDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                </span>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

                @if (Model.CEOUser != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CEOUser.ToString()) && Model.CEOUser > 0)
                {
                    <tr style="height: 5px;">
                        <td style="width: 76mm;">
                            <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">@Model.CEOUserName</label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">
                            <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">CEO</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:38mm;">

                            @if (@Model.CEOApproved == true)
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Approved</label>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">Rejected</label>
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 38mm;">

                            @if (@Model.CEOApprovalDate != null)
                            {
                                <span class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="font-weight:normal;">
                                    @Model.CEOApprovalDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                </span>
                            }


                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }

            </table>

    </div>
    <div class="container" style="border-top: solid 1px; margin-top: 1px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 5px; ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="col-md-12" style="align-items: center;display:flex;justify-content: center;flex-direction: row;margin-top:10px;margin-left:-50px;">
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left:5px;">
                        <label class="requestInfo-lable-1">
                            CEO
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div style="width: 40mm; border-bottom: solid 1px;margin-left:7px;">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left:160px;">
                        <label class="requestInfo-lable-1">
                            Received By
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div style="width: 40mm; border-bottom: solid 1px;margin-left:7px;">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">


                <div class="col-md-12" style="align-items: center;display:flex;justify-content: center;flex-direction: row;margin-top:10px;">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="margin-left:-200px;">
                            Signature and Date
                        </label>


                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="requestInfo-lable-1" style="margin-left:130px;">
                            Signature and Date
                        </label>

                    </div>



                </div>

                <div class="footer">
                    <div style="font-family:'Bold'">  HR FM 04-03-E   <span> Version No: 09. Effective Date : 15/03/2020</span> </div>

                </div>



    </div>
```

and CSS file as below :

```
@page {
    size: auto; /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm; /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}

body {
    /*height:29.7cm;
    width:21cm;
    margin: 20mm 18mm;*/
    margin-top: 20mm;
    margin-left: 21mm;
}
/*@page {
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    margin: 20mm 18mm;
}*/

.container {
    width: 17cm;
    border: solid 2px black;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
    /* display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:34mm 102mm 34mm;*/
    display: flex;
}

.header-HRlogo {
    width: 34mm;
    border-right: solid 2px black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header-Title {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.header-CompanyLogo {
    width: 34mm;
    border-left: solid 2px black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.requestInfo {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.requestInfo-lable-1 {
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-weight: bold;
    /*padding: 1px 10px;*/
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.requestInfo-lable-2 {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.requestInfo-flex-div-1 {
    width: 37mm;
}

.requestInfo-flex-div-2 {
    width: 50mm;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    text-align: center;
}

.requestInfo-flex-div-4 {
    width: 57mm;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.modelData {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.square {
    padding: 1px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: flex;
}

.checkMark {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}


.tableBorderCollaps {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0px;
}

.footer {
    font-size: 6.5px;
    margin-left: 4.5mm;
    margin-top: 2mm;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)